# Use LTE laptop for cellular phone calls

Tags: cellular-network, lte

I want to use my laptop with LTE modem (and SIM card slot) for regular calls, using the phone number associated with my SIM. From my current operator, and also some forums, I got an answer that it is not possible.

## Why?

I still would like to know a technical reasons behind it. Whether it is just a matter of software (that nobody has created a Dialer/Phone app which could be installed on a 64bit linux or windows system), or there is something else making this impossible.

## Natively, 4G (or LTE) is only for data

I understand that when a smartphone is connected to an internet via 4G (LTE), and a call is established, it reverts to 3G or 2G network. This would make sense that if a laptop's broadband module only supports 4G, it is not able to do so.

## How about VoLTE?

I still think that it should be possible via VoLTE. There are even apps for android to convert an LTE phone (which natively does not support VoLTE) to utilize [VoLTE](https://www.cspsprotocol.com/convert-lte-to-volte/).

Do you have any experience with matter of Calling or sending SMS using 4G? Are there any apps, or at least APIs which I could use to implement it? Or am I missing something in facts I have explained above?